# R: Grouping and summarizing data to find the nth nearest event after date of reference

Tags: r, datetime, group-by, summarize, data-wrangling

I have been working with a dataset that contains the CLIENT (identification), date of creation of an account (DATE ENTER) and the GATE use for customers in order to place orders in a website (Table A), but some of these attempts fail and that why a second data frame (Table B) is provided with the  CLIENT (identification), the ERROR_DATE and the MAGIC_IP that identifies the error as a side note all GATES and all MAGIC_IPs will always be different even if this implies the same customer  identification.

Table A

| GATE | CLIENT | DATE_ENTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 3 |
| D | 1 | 4 |
| E | 1 | 5 |
| F | 1 | 6 |
| G | 1 | 7 |
| H | 1 | 8 |
| I | 1 | 9 |
| J | 1 | 10 |
| K | 1 | 11 |
| L | 1 | 12 |
| M | 1 | 16 |

Table B

| HOST | CLIENT | DATE_ERROR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14558556 | 1 | 2 |
| 14558557 | 1 | 3 |
| 14558558 | 1 | 4 |
| 14558559 | 1 | 5 |
| 14558560 | 1 | 6 |
| 14558561 | 1 | 7 |
| 14558562 | 3 | 8 |
| 14558563 | 2 | 9 |
| 14558564 | 3 | 10 |
| 14558565 | 3 | 11 |
| 14558566 | 1 | 12 |
| 14558567 | 1 | 13 |

What I want to create is a table where I can see for each "CLIENT","DATE ENTER" and "GATE" what was the  ERROR_DATE and MAGIC_IP immediately  after or in other words the very next one.  The expected result should look like this:

| GATE | CLIENT | DATE_ENTER | DATE_ERROR | MAGIC_IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2 | 154 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 2 | 154 |
| C | 1 | 3 | 4 | 156 |
| D | 1 | 4 | 5 | 157 |
| E | 1 | 5 | 6 | 158 |
| F | 1 | 6 | 7 | 159 |
| G | 1 | 7 | 10 | 160 |
| H | 1 | 8 | 10 | 160 |
| I | 1 | 9 | 10 | 160 |
| J | 1 | 10 | 11 | 163 |
| K | 1 | 11 | 12 | 164 |
| L | 1 | 12 | 13 | 165 |
| M | 1 | 16 | N.A | N.A |

In this table I am able to see for each GATE. CLIENT AND "DATE_ENTER" what was the very next or the closest nearest MAGIC_IP and ERROR_DATE for each client, thank you so much to everyone willing to help me out,

What have I tried?

I was thinking about grouping by CLIENT,DATE_ENTER and GATE after left joining the two tables by CLIENT, and then create a variable that would subtract all the dates and pick for each group the smallest positive value as an index to correlate the information about MAGIC_IP and ERROR_DATE, but I cant seem to find a way to do so at the moment thank you for all of your help guys

Data:

```
TableA<-tribble(~GATE,  ~CLIENT,    ~DATE_ENTER,
"A",    "1",    "1",
"B",    "1",    "1",
"C",    "1",    "3",
"D",    "1",    "4",
"E",    "1",    "5",
"F",    "1",    "6",
"G",    "1",    "7",
"H",    "1",    "8",
"I",    "1",    "9",
"J",    "1",    "10",
"K",    "1",    "11",
"L",    "1",    "12")

TableB<-tribble(~HOST,  ~CLIENT,    ~DATE_ERROR,
                "14558556", "1",    "2",
                "14558557", "1",    "3",
                "14558558", "1",    "4",
                "14558559", "1",    "5",
                "14558560", "1",    "6",
                "14558561", "1",    "7",
                "14558562", "3",    "8",
                "14558563", "2",    "9",
                "14558564", "3",    "10",
                "14558565", "3",    "11",
                "14558566", "1",    "12",
                "14558567", "1",    "13")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `TableA` and `TableB` by `CLIENT` and select the row which is the smallest positive difference between `DATE_ERROR` and `DATE_ENTER`.

```
library(dplyr)

TableA %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(TableB, by = 'CLIENT') %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  filter({tmp = DATE_ERROR - DATE_ENTER
          tmp == min(tmp[tmp > 0], na.rm = TRUE)
          }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your code worked perfectly I have a question how would I go about creating a variable to identify the number of the groups created by group_by? Thanks a lot my friend

Comment: In this case every row is considered as one group.